# Chrome rendering an alert() box with the last 2 words on 2 separate lines. How to fix?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have the following JS that produces an alert box:

```
alert("You have selected the maximum number of funds available for comparison. Please ensure only five funds have been selected for your basket");
```

Chrome is rendering the alert box like this:

[image]

with the last 2 words wrapping onto separate lines.

Has anyone seen this before? Any ideas how to fix this?!

---

Wanted to add another screenshot since I am able to reproduce this error:
--Jeremy

[image]

Comment: Bizarre; it's not doing that to me with your "alert()", but I'm using Chrome on Linux so maybe that makes a difference.

Comment: Works ok for me, chrome 12, windows.

Comment: This is extremely odd. I can confirm this with Chrome 11 on XP. Any words I put after "basket" seem to flow normally, yet the line break after "your" persists.

Comment: @Jeremy, This image was actually supplied by the client, and I think she's using Chrome 8. I'm using 11 on Windows 7, and it works fine for me.. It's interesting that you're on XP with version 11 and you're seeing this also.

I think the culprit is Chrome on XP with the word 'basket'? (for some odd reason).. at least I have something to go with now. (though *where*, I don't know!)

Comment: @DaveDev - get your client to update their Chrome version -- v12 has been released, so it should update for them automatically. If it's a Chrome bug there's a good chance it'll magically come right after the update.

Comment: @DaveDev, It doesn't seem that the word basket really is affecting anything. I can put other words there, between 4-7 characters and it still has the odd line break. If I keep adding more lines, I get another odd line break after 4 extra lines (on top of the existing three).

Comment: @Spudley: That's not always an option (or easy) when behind a corporate firewall.

Comment: @Jeremy, I've tried installing old versions of Chrome on an XP machine, and Google 'helpfully' automatically updated the browser to version 12. Could you please run the code with the line breaks as outlined in @dr jimbob's answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6330878/chrome-rendering-an-alert-box-with-the-last-2-words-on-2-separate-lines-how-to/6331223#6331223

I have no other way of testing. If you could post a screenshot, I'll buy you a beer (if you ever make your way to Ireland!)

Comment: @DaveDev: Any excuse to visit Ireland! Haha. (Posted image as an answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@DaveDev, here is the image you requested. I think it looks good enough.

The code is from @dr jimbob's answer.

[image]

Comment: thanks man.. this gives me something I can go to the client with as a solution.

Answer (score 5):

This seems to be a bug with older verisons of Chrome.

http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=83670

In Chrome 12 on linux it works fine, so I can't easily reproduce/debug.  Have you tried putting in your own line breaks, say after every 70 characters like:

```
alert("You have selected the maximum number of funds \n"+
      "available for comparison. Please ensure only five \n"+
      "funds have been selected for your basket.");
```

I understand hard-coding linebreaks is a bad idea in general (in some cases they will be poor choices) or if the text ever changes the line breaks will have to be adjusted by you.

As a programmer/developer you can't fully account for chrome not working properly.  Except maybe avoiding `alert` box entirely, and sending the error message another way (e.g., ajax or a custom alert from say [jquery](http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/alert)).

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. I'll give it a try, once the sysadmins get me an XP box to poke around on. RE your point about avoiding the `alert` box entirely, believe me the `\n`'s will do!! I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: I installed an old version of Chrome (v9) and it automatically updated that to version 12, so I couldn't test.

Comment: +1 for this. this is a difficult thing for me to do, but I've had to award the 'correct' answer to @Jeremy Heiler. The reason for this is because he was able to prove that this worked, and in doing so it's something that I can go back to the client with as a suggestion.

Comment: @DaveDev: no worries.  +40 reputation is more than enough for the level of expertise/work required for my answer (next to none).  Even my answer was near identical to elvenbytes (+1).

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to you that you, as a programmer, controll the length of each string. You can cut the line, by yourself, with a '\n' character, and control every line for yourself.

Comment: This kind of defeats the purpose of an alert box that is **supposed** to wrap the text for you.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect there is a line end in your document, because testing it in my Chrome (12, windows 7), the alert displays like it should. Are you using HTMLTidy or some HTML formatter?

[*edit*] Okay, seems to be a genuine Chrome issue. Here some related issues @code.google.com for Chrome

- [Lengthy alerts have weird line break in them](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=77231)
- [Long text messages get truncated on the Javascript Alert box](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=2441)
- [javascript alert popup truncates strings every 132 chars](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=77037)

Comment: Another user's confirmed the behavior, so it looks like a genuine Chrome weirdness.

Comment: @Pointy: I saw that after writing my answer. Seems like a Chrome(11)/win XP combination.

Comment: @Pointy & @Kooilnc, the client is using Chrome 8, so the weirdness goes for at least a *few* versions of Chrome on XP. Should I report this as a bug?

Comment: @DaveDev: I'm not sure. Since it's an old Chrome version, maybe you should first check if the error persists using Chrome12/XP. If it does and you file a bug report, it's likely they will do something about it, otherwise I imagine the Chrome devs are not going to fix errors for older versions.

Answer (score 1):

The solution I have stumbled upon is to add +"\ " (backslash space) at the end of the string. Each of my text lines ends with a \n in any case, so effectively my string now ends with "\n\ "Then it seems I can use as many \n's that I want. Don't ask me why it works. Perhaps it will work for you? Just call me persistent!